# Finding possible values of $\det(X)$ when $AX-XA=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given matrix  $
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1  \\
-1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ such that 
$AX-XA=A \tag{1}\label{1}$
where $X$ is a matrix with integer entries of order 2.
We need to find which of the following options are NOT possible for $\det(X)$.

1. 10
2. 6
3. 2
4. 0

**My attempt:** I took
$X=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

and on substituting and solving $\eqref{1}$, I got following:

- $b+c=1$
- $a+c=b+d$
- On solving for $b$ and $c$ ,I got $a$ and $d$ must be of opposite parity (even/odd)

How can I further proceed? Do I have to guess the possible entries of X or there is a brief or better way to solve it quickly. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions you found can be solved for $c$ and $a$ (for example):
\begin{align}
c &= 1 - b\\
a &= 2b + d - 1
\end{align}
Now given the form of $X$ that you chose, it's clear that
$\det(X) = ad - bc$, which can be reduced to:
\begin{align}
ad-bc&= (2b + d - 1)d + b^2 - b\\
&=d^2 + b^2 - (d + b) + 2bd \\
&=(d + b)^2 - (d + b) \\
&= x^2 - x
\end{align}
Where $x = d + b$. Hence $x^2 - x - \det(X) = 0$. Now substitute in the potential values for $\det(X)$ and see which result in a polynomial with integer roots.